# argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to retrieve data using json map and firestore but getting "The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'" error on this line

```
posts.map(buildPost).toList(),
```

body

```
StreamBuilder<List<Post>>(
        stream: readPost(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('somthing went wrong');
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final posts = snapshot.data;
            return ListView(
              children: posts.map(buildPost).toList(),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
```

readPost Method

```
  Stream<List<Post>> readPost() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Posts')
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) =>
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Post.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
```

buildPost method

```
buildPost(Post post) => ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
        title: Text(post.title),
        subtitle: Text(post.subject),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function

```
buildPost(Post post) => ListTile()
```

to

```
Widget buildPost(Post post) => ListTile()
```